# Change timezone based on data from another column

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my example dataframe:

```
                     Office  Design  ...          SiteLog Duration
0          DQFEMOZM - 2141  ZMI_PE  ...   6/28/2019 7:59        6
1          DQFEMOZM - 2141  ZMI_PE  ...   6/28/2019 7:47        5
2          DQFEMOZM - 2141  ZMI_PE  ...   6/27/2019 4:58        2
3          DQFEMOZM - 2141  ZMI_PE  ...   6/27/2019 4:52        2
4        YMTSZUXXQN - 1031  ZMI_PE  ...    6/3/2019 4:10        4
6        YMTSZUXXQN - 1031  ZMI_PE  ...   6/2/2019 22:36        6
9            UTUXMW - 1046  ZMI_PE  ...  6/26/2019 20:01      336
10           UTUXMW - 1046  ZMI_PE  ...  6/26/2019 14:16      828
11           UTUXMW - 1046  ZMI_PE  ...  6/14/2019 16:33        2
12           UTUXMW - 1046  ZMI_PE  ...  6/14/2019 15:07        2
14  GMUH-FZAB XMHMX - 2114  ZMI_PE  ...   6/25/2019 5:35        3
15      TSGADANXDMY - 1215  ZMI_PE  ...    6/9/2019 3:10        3
16      TSGADANXDMY - 1215  ZMI_PE  ...   6/8/2019 19:03        2
17      TSGADANXDMY - 1215  ZMI_PE  ...    6/8/2019 3:59        2
18          PDARPQY - 1154  ZMI_PE  ...   6/30/2019 7:06        1
19          PDARPQY - 1154  ZMI_PE  ...   6/18/2019 5:04      216
21      MSGMEEUEEUY - 2027  ZMI_PE  ...  6/27/2019 17:36        2
23      MSGMEEUEEUY - 2027  ZMI_PE  ...    6/4/2019 9:32       11
25      MSGMEEUEEUY - 2027  ZMI_PE  ...   6/2/2019 22:37        4
26      MSGMEEUEEUY - 2027  ZMI_PE  ...   6/2/2019 22:25        2
28      MSGMEEUEEUY - 2027  ZMI_PE  ...  5/29/2019 23:24        2
```

All the example site logs are in PST. What I'm trying to do is take certain rows, say office "DQFEMOZM - 2141" and change the site log timestamp to EST.

I've tried using the tz_localize and tz_convert functions but haven't been able to get them to work.

```
import pandas as pd
from pytz import all_timezones
data = pd.read_csv('lab.csv')
data = data.drop_duplicates('SiteLog')
data = data.drop(data[data.Duration == 0].index) 
DQFEMOZM = data[data.Office == 'DQFEMOZM - 2141'].index
DQFEMOZM = DQFEMOZM.tz_localize('America/Los_Angeles')
DQFEMOZM = DQFEMOZM.tz_convert('America/New_York')
```

Part of the error message I'm receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    DQFEMOZM = DQFEMOZM.tz_convert('America/New_York')
AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'tz_convert'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning index to `data` which makes it `Int64`. You can accomplish the task like the following:

```
from pandas import Timestamp
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("/Users/user/Desktop/Book6.csv")
data = data.drop_duplicates("SiteLog")

for office, datetime in zip(data["Office"], data["SiteLog"]):
    if office == "DQFEMOZM - 2141":
        raw_time = Timestamp(datetime)
        print(raw_time)
        loc_raw_time = raw_time.tz_localize("America/Los_Angeles")
        print(loc_raw_time)
        new_raw_time = loc_raw_time.tz_convert("America/New_York")
        print(new_raw_time)
```

I used first two rows for example:

```
                     Office  Design  ...          SiteLog Duration
0          DQFEMOZM - 2141  ZMI_PE  ...   6/28/2019 7:59        6
1          DQFEMOZM - 2141  ZMI_PE  ...   6/28/2019 7:47        5
```

and the code output is (for your reference I am just printing all the time zones that you transfer),

```
2019-06-28 07:59:00
2019-06-28 07:59:00-07:00
2019-06-28 10:59:00-04:00
2019-06-28 07:47:00
2019-06-28 07:47:00-07:00
2019-06-28 10:47:00-04:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert time like that.  You'll need to use the pytz and the datetime module.

```
import pytz, datetime
```

I started out with smaller data frame to test.

```
>>> data = pd.read_csv ('test.csv')
>>> df = pd.DataFrame (data)
>>> df
              Office  Design         SiteLog  Duration
0    DQFEMOZM - 2141  ZMI_PE  6/28/2019 7:59         6
1      UTUXMW - 1046  ZMI_PE  6/28/2019 7:47         5
2  YMTSZUXXQN - 1031  ZMI_PE  6/27/2019 4:58         2
3    DQFEMOZM - 2144  ZMI_PE  6/27/2019 4:52         2
```

Next, create a date/time conversion function.

```
>>> def date_conversion (df):
...     nytimes = []
...     for i, record in enumerate (df.Office):
...         if 'DQFEMOZM - 2141' in record:
...             time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(df.SiteLog [i], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')  # Convert string into date/time object for localization and conversion
...             pacific_time = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles').localize(time_obj)
...             new_york_time = pacific_time.astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))
...             nytimes.append(new_york_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))  # Converting time object back to string
...         else:
...             nytimes.append ('-')
...     return nytimes
```

Finally, insert the converted time to your dataframe.

```
>>> df.insert (3, 'SiteLog_NY', date_conversion (df), True)
>>> df
              Office  Design         SiteLog        SiteLog_NY  Duration
0    DQFEMOZM - 2141  ZMI_PE  6/28/2019 7:59  06/28/2019 10:59         6
1      UTUXMW - 1046  ZMI_PE  6/28/2019 7:47                 -         5
2  YMTSZUXXQN - 1031  ZMI_PE  6/27/2019 4:58                 -         2
3    DQFEMOZM - 2144  ZMI_PE  6/27/2019 4:52                 -         2
```

Comment: You are checking the conditioning cause you need to change to only specific office.

Comment: You need to specify why you did -1 to my answer. It is not a good practice just to demote an answer. I noticed that you did it by your score reduction.

Comment: Your answer is not what the user asked. I produced the right answer.